# compare columns

Tags: unix, awk

I have two files:

file1

```
1 
2 
3
4
5
```

file2

```
a     0     1    h    f  
b     0     3    h    f
c     0     8    h    f
d     0     5    h    f
```

I want to compare file1 to column3 of file2 and print the whole row of file2 like this

```
a     0     1     h    f
b     0     3     h    f 
d     0     5     h    f
```

I tried using `awk` but I am printing the column3:

```
awk 'NR == FNR {f2[$3]=$1; next} $1 in f2{print f2[$1],$1}' file2 file1
```

How can I print the whole rows from file2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much easier if you give `file1` first:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$3 in a' file1 file2
a     0     1    h    f
b     0     3    h    f
d     0     5    h    f
```

This way you can easily print the whole line in `file2` if the value in field three is in `file1`. The default block is in `awk` is `{print $0}` so it can be omitted from `$3 in a{print $0}`.

Comment: does it take the unique numbers from file1,because i see decrease in number of lines@sudo_O

Comment: @user2133307 I am not sure what you mean? If the value in `field 3` from `file2` is also in `file1` then whole line will be printed. If this is not correct please update the question with **representative** input files and the expected output.

Comment: like if the file1 has two 3's or 5's(repeated)like this 1,2,3,4,3,5,5.what does it print(only once) sudo_O

Comment: The script I posted **does not** print anything from `file1`. It does only build the array in which the comparison is done with unique values from `file1` as duplicates aren't helpful. Are you saying that if the value `1` is in `file1` once but in `file2, field 3` twice the output should only display the first match? **You need to edit the question with REPRESENTATIVE input and expected output if this is a requirement!**

Comment: @user2133307 - if you're concerned about input that doesn't follow the format of the input you posted in your question (e.g. with duplicate field3 values), then update your question to show the REPRESENTATIVE input you actually care about plus the expected output for that input.

Comment: sorry i was confused,the reason why i was asking is that i have repeated same numbers in the file1 and i thought i could print every match as it appears but now i made the file1 unique and and then overlapped,thank you for the help @sudo_O